# How to delete a record only if the user posted is the logged in user

Tags: django

I have multiple users in my project
my models.py file is

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name='Teacher')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    teacher_profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="classroom/teacher_profile_pic",blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Announcement(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

If the logged in user is a teacher it is allowed to create an announcement
Now i want that only the teacher who posted the announcement should be able to see the delete button

My html file is

```
{% extends "classroom/base.html" %} 
{% block content %}
<h1>Announcements</h1>
{% for announcement in announcements %} 
    <!-- starting loop (posts is keyword from view) -->

  <div style="border-style: solid;">
      {% if object.teacher.id == request.teacher %}
        <div>
            <a href="{% url 'classroom:opt'  %}">Delete</a>
        </div>
      {% endif %}   
      <a class="mr-2">Posted by: {{ announcement.teacher }}</a>
      <h2><a class="article-title">{{ announcement.title }}</a></h2>
      <p class="article-content">{{ announcement.content}}</p>
  </div>
        
    {% endfor %} 
{% endblock content %}
```

the `if statement` is supposed to be true if logged in teacher is the teacher who originally posted it. However the delete button is visible for every announcement

my views.py has

```
class AnnouncementListView(ListView):
    context = {
            'announcements' : Announcement.objects.all()
        }
    model  =  Announcement
    template_name = 'classroom/all_announcements.html' 
    context_object_name = 'announcements'
```

Comment: This might work `object.teacher.id == request.user.Teacher.id`.. Requestt object does not have teacher object I believe .

Comment: it enabled the delete button for all announcements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this.

```
{% if announcement.teacher.user == request.user %}
       <div>
         <a href="{% url 'classroom:opt'  %}">Delete</a>
      </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: this way disappeared the delete button for all announcements

Comment: Try what this will give  `{{announcement.teacher.user}}` ? @AreebaAkhtar

Comment: it returned the username

Comment: username of currently logged in user/teacher

Answer (score 0):

Your models are a bit "unconventional".

However, this should work:

```py
{% if announcement.teacher.user == request.user %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: the above mentioned way disappeared the delete button for all announcements

Comment: Weird. Can you confirm in the database that the Announcements objects are correct?